# Geowebcache disk quota is different from tile layers page

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

[image]

This is my disk quota page and following is my tile layers list page:

[image]

And I could not found my tiled images in server data directory.

[image]

I think my tiles are not saving on disk. What is the problem that you think?

Comment: I had the same error in interface, but i checked tiles were in the GWC cache. I think is a interface error parsing a number or some like this...

Comment: I can not check my tiles because GWC folder is not created in data folder. If I cereate manually, does it work?

Comment: The directory to store tiles must exist or you'd see errors in the Geoserver interface. The directory "gwc-layers" sounds similar, Did you check it?. The GWC directory is configured in a context variable (GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR or some like this), or stored in the "web.xml" in Geoserver file. This directory could be changed in your Geoserver instance...

Comment: If you don't set explicilty the GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR GWC will create tiles under the system tmp directory for the user that started the java process inside the geowebcache directory.

As an instance on windows that path for me is C:\Users\geosolutions\AppData\Local\Temp\geowebcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem to this (Ubuntu 14.04, GeoServer 2.6.1). Geoserver/GeoWebCache was storing tiles in the temporary storage directory specified by the web app container (with the side-effect of the cache being emptied whenever the servlet was restarted).

I resolved this by:

- Creating a new directory in the geoserver data directory (for me,
  this was /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc) - I ran into trouble setting it to locations outside of the geoserver directory.
- Changing the permissions of the directory to be owned by tomcat (chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc).
- Adding the reference to the new directory to the geoserver web.xml (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/config.html#changing-the-cache-directory)
- Restarting tomcat (service tomcat7 restart)

Regarding the negative disk usage, I resolved this by removing the .db files from inside the diskquote_page_store directory (see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-5615)